# How to loop over data-frame; sort by row and paste new values in a more faster way?

Tags: r, loops, sorting

My objective is to create a naive TOP-N-list:

- I would like to loop over a data-frame (or matrix) by row
- sort values (decreasing) by row
- and afterwards *paste the specific column name* (of sorted) data
- finally: store data into a new data-frame or matrix.

**Example of INPUT df_numbers**

```
X1  | X2  | X3  | ... | 
1   | 3   | 8   | ... |
```

**Example of OUTPUT TOP_N**

```
X1  | X2  | X3  | ... | 
X3  | X2  | X1  | ... |
```

My function, that works "well", is the following one:  
BUT on larger data sets it takes too much to time to processing - is there a faster alternative to do it?

```
n <- length(df_numbers)
rank <- 0:9 #(total number of columns of df_numbers)
TOP_N <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df_numbers), ncol = 10))

for (i in 1:nrow(df_numbers)){
        TOP_N[i,]  <- names(sort(df_numbers[i,],partial=n-rank)[n-rank])

        # Progressbar
        if (i %% 1000==0) { cat(paste0("Iteration: ", i, "\n")) }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the `paste the specific column names` part. Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm confused about the difference between `df_numbers` and `df_probabilities`. Can you post some example data? If you can post enough code so that we can copy/paste and run it, you will get help **much** faster.

Comment: Also I'm confused by `rank`. How is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` the "number of columns of `df_numbers`"? Why does it start with 0? Does this mean there are 9 columns? 10 columns? Something else?

Comment: @Gregor: it was a typing error and is fixed in the code snippet. "rank" started by zero because of the "partial attribute" in sort() and represents in total numbers of existing columns

Comment: @CPak I have added an example to visualize the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things will work *much* faster on matrices than data frames.

```
# example data (include something like this in your question!!)
n = 1000
set.seed(47)
input = matrix(c(rpois(n, 50)), ncol = n / 100)
colnames(input) = paste0("X", 1:ncol(input))

# Solution
sorted = t(apply(input, MARGIN = 1, FUN = order))
result = matrix(colnames(input)[sorted], ncol = ncol(input))

# demo
head(input)
#      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# [1,] 64 48 55 53 40 51 52 41 45  53
# [2,] 55 47 53 58 36 48 49 40 37  44
# [3,] 51 46 58 38 44 49 52 50 53  43
# [4,] 48 54 45 46 45 39 50 48 47  46
# [5,] 50 54 56 59 52 54 49 48 43  34
# [6,] 42 45 58 55 58 59 56 56 58  44

head(result)
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,] "X5"  "X8"  "X9" "X2"  "X6"  "X7" "X4" "X10" "X3" "X1" 
# [2,] "X5"  "X9"  "X8" "X10" "X2"  "X6" "X7" "X3"  "X1" "X4" 
# [3,] "X4"  "X10" "X5" "X2"  "X6"  "X8" "X1" "X7"  "X9" "X3" 
# [4,] "X6"  "X3"  "X5" "X4"  "X10" "X9" "X1" "X8"  "X7" "X2" 
# [5,] "X10" "X9"  "X8" "X7"  "X1"  "X5" "X2" "X6"  "X3" "X4" 
# [6,] "X1"  "X10" "X2" "X4"  "X7"  "X8" "X3" "X5"  "X9" "X6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mtcars` as an example, you could

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(mtcars, 1, function(i) colnames(mtcars)[order(i, decreasing=TRUE)])))

                      # V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11
# Mazda RX4           disp   hp  mpg qsec  cyl gear carb drat   wt   am   vs
# Mazda RX4 Wag       disp   hp  mpg qsec  cyl gear carb drat   wt   am   vs
# Datsun 710          disp   hp  mpg qsec  cyl gear drat   wt   vs   am carb
# Hornet 4 Drive      disp   hp  mpg qsec  cyl   wt drat gear   vs carb   am
# Hornet Sportabout   disp   hp  mpg qsec  cyl   wt drat gear carb   vs   am
# Valiant             disp   hp qsec  mpg  cyl   wt gear drat   vs carb   am
```